# Save function using button in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a doubt on the following code. My function is not called when the save button is clicked .

This is the following code for save function,

```
 if(isset($_POST['Save'])) // If the submit button was clicked
    {
        echo "hgfd";
        $post['ProductSegmentCode'] = $_POST['ProductSegmentCode'];
        $post['ProductSegment'] = $_POST['ProductSegment'];
        $post['ProductGroup'] = $_POST['productgroup'];

        // This will make sure its displayed
        if(!empty($_POST['ProductSegment'])&&!empty($_POST['ProductSegmentCode'])&&!empty($_POST['productgroup']))
        {   

                echo "SAVE";
             $news->addNews($post);
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Created Sucessfully..!!");
            </script>
            <?
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Enter Mandatory Fields");
            </script>
            <?
        }
    }
```

following is the button format in html,

```
<div style="width:70px; height:32px; float:left; margin-top:16px; margin-left:4px;">

                      <input name="Save" type="button" class="button" value="Save">
                           </div>
```

Comment: button format in html missing?

Comment: What is `onclick="Save"` supposed to do? Is there an accompanying Javascript function? Are you misunderstanding how PHP and forms interact?

Comment: put ` print_r($_POST)`before `isset()` clause and see whats being posted, that will get you futher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is `type="button"`; to get the form to submit, it needs to be `type="submit"`. Try updating it with this and it should work (also pending you form has `action="post"`, or no action specified; the default is `post`):

```
<input name="Save" type="submit" class="button" value="Save" onclick="Save" />
```

Also, you're using `onclick="Save"` in your button. This indicates you have a corresponding JavaScript function named `Save()` - though, per your code examples you do not show one. I'm assuming that this is in error and can safely be removed (the `value="Save"` can also be removed as you only need to check `isset($_POST['Save'])` and not it's actual value). All changes in-place should give you:

```
<input name="Save" type="submit" class="button" />
```

If you do, in fact, have a JavaScript function named `Save()`, please post its code and I can revise.

Answer (score 0):

use `form` for sending data and use type `submit`

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="Save" type="submit" class="button" value="Save">
</form>
```

and if you want to use this

```
<input name="Save" type="button" class="button" value="Save" onclick="Save()">
```

create `Save()` function in javascript and use `ajax` call for sending data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should change

```
<input name="Save" type="button" class="button" value="Save" onclick="Save">
```

to a summit button.

```
<input name="Save" type="submit" class="button" value="Save">
```